# How to inject every possible implementation of an interface as a dependency in the constructor in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a Factory class:

```
@Service
class AffectedObjectServiceFactory {

    private static final Map<String, AffectedObjectService> affectedObjectServiceMap = new HashMap<>();
    @Autowired
    private AffectedObjectServiceFactory(List<AffectedObjectService> services) {
        for(AffectedObjectService service : services) {
            String[] supportedSubTypes = service.func1();
            for (String subType: supportedSubTypes) {
                affectedObjectServiceMap.put(subType, service);
            }
        }
    }

    public static AffectedObjectService getAffectedObject(String type) {
        AffectedObjectService affectedObjectService = affectedObjectServiceMap.get(type);
        if(affectedObjectService == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown service type: " + type);
        return affectedObjectService;
    }
}
```

here are the interfaces and its implementations

```
interface AffectedObjectService {
    String func1();
}

@Component
class AffectedObjectServiceImpl1 implements AffectedObjectService {
    @Override
    String func1() { //.... }
}

@Component
class AffectedObjectServiceImpl2 implements AffectedObjectService {
    @Override
    String func1() { //.... }
}

@Component
class AffectedObjectServiceImpl3 implements AffectedObjectService {

    XYZInterface type;
    @Autowired
    AffectedObjectServiceImpl3(XYZInterface type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    String func1() { //.... }
}

Interface XYZInterface {
     String func2();
}

@Component
class XYZInterfaceImpl1 extends XYZInterface {
    @Override
    String func2() { // .... }
}

@Component
class XYZInterfaceImpl2 extends XYZInterface {
    @Override
    String func2() { // .... }
}
```

The `AffectedObjectService` is an interface which is implemented by multiple classes. Some classes have further a constructor which takes another interface implementation as parameters.
How can I pass every possible `AffectedObjectServiceImpl3` (one with XYZInterfaceImpl1 as parameter, and one with XYZInterfaceImpl2 as parameter) as dependency to the constructor of the Factory class?

Comment: Are they all registered as services / some beans?

Comment: sorry made a mistake in my question. i;ve reupdated it with different code

Comment: In general your code should work, however I'm not sure about two following points: 1. private constructor. 2. calling AffectedObjectService#func1 in constructor - that causes premature initialization of bean